# Shell Script Command not found but works in terminal

Tags: shell

I am printing out a simple command that works in terminal

```
> nmv --version
```

But it does not work in my shell script. I have the script in the image here.

[image]

Comment: Just specify the full path to nvm.

Comment: @RedCricket sorry how can I get the full path to nvm ? Also, why this might be happening ?

Comment: Execute `which nvm` in the terminal.

Comment: Did. Im getting a blank return. I think it means there is no path to it ? Although nvm --version is working fine.

Comment: Why is this happening with you test.sh script? Who knows. You didn't post the script. Maybe you `su ` to a user how doesn't have their `PATH` env var set up right.  Maybe your script stomps on the PATH env var.

Comment: I found this on nvm's github page "Please note that which nvm will not work, since nvm is a sourced shell function, not an executable binary."

Comment: If `which` couldn't find nvm it would output something like `which: no nvm in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/…`. So who knows what you're doing wrong there.

Comment: My test script is as shown in the picture. #!/bin/bash
echo hello
nvm --version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nvm docs say …

> The script clones the nvm repository to ~/.nvm and adds the source
>   line to your profile (~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc, ~/.profile, or
>   ~/.bashrc).

… so look in your `~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc, ~/.profile, or ~/.bashrc` files for the source command the nvm install script added and use that same source command in your test.sh script.

Try adding these lines to the start of your script:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" 
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

Comment: I have the following lines in ~/.bashrc : `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion` Can you help me with the command in my test script

Comment: I guess you could `source ~/.bashrc` in your script.

Comment: I added `source ~/.bashrc` to my script. Unfortunately it doesnt work :( getting same error. Ill give it up at this point. Cannot thank you enough for your patience and responses.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: Thanks! It did work. I dont understand what this export statement does. I do get that nvm's install script adds this statement. Thanks anyways